# reading a file from .apk

Tags: java, android, swing, apk

I have **a jar** which is located in `/libs` folder in my android project. The jar has some **xml files**.

What I want to do is read the `xml` file from the jar in my android app.

I have tried using the below method :

```
      private String loadFromJar(String p_strFileName) {
            try {
                String strPath = p_strFileName;
                InputStream stream = this.class.getResourceAsStream(strPath);
                if (stream == null) {
                    System.err.println(" stream is null for " + strPath);
                } else {
                    int av = (stream.available() / 200) + 1;
                    int i = 0;
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    while (i <= av) {
                        try {
                            byte[] a = new byte[200];
                            stream.read(a);
                            sb.append(new String(a, "UTF-8"));
                            i++;
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                  return sb.toString();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "jarfile is null for " + p_strFileName);
            }
           return "";
        }
```

However, It does not work.

I have also tried to do same thing in a java swing application And It works.

I guess apk file behaviour is different from jar file

I know that I can read a file from res folder or in a assets folder. However, this is not a solution for my case. Because the jar is platform-independent library. And I want to use the library to get the files just like I do in other platforms such as desktop platforms.

Comment: why don't you use assets!? just put your xml into assets

Comment: Because my library has already the files. Why should I put them manually in my android application ?

Answer (score -1):

I have tried to several way to read the file from jar in a android project.

Finally I can read the file using this :

```
InputStream stream = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(strPath);
```

The below codes does no work.

```
InputStream stream = MyFragment.class.getResourceAsStream(strPath); // fails
InputStream stream = getClass().getResourceAsStream(p_strFilePath); // fails
```